# Namedtuple that store point

Tags: python, point, namedtuple

I want make a variable that store some points in one ROI.
Let say it is something like:

```
ROI.Point1.x
ROI.Point1.y
ROI.Point2.x
ROI.Point2.y
 ...
ROI.PointN.x
ROI.PointN.y
```

I tried to make this with `namedtuple`, like so:

```
Point = namedtuple("Point", "x y")
ROI = namedtuple("ROI", "Point1 Point2 Point3 ... PointN")
ROI.Point1 = Point
ROI.Point2 = Point
...
ROI.PointN = Point
```

I think that is stupid idea. Because I must define all of the point with *"ROI... = Point"*.

If I just have 1 ROI and some point in it I think it works OK. But what about having many ROI with many Points in them? It seems a silly idea, but so far it works.

I also tried to use `ROI.Point1, ROI.Point2, ..., ROI.PointN = Point` but I got an error that says `'type' object is not iterable`.

Could someone help me to make it work in a simpler fashion, please? I didn't want make another class like other people do.

Comment: Why don't you use tuple or list to store multiple points?

Comment: You don't do `ROI.Point1 = Point`. You'd do `ROI(Point(x1, y1), Point(..), ..)`. `ROI` and `Point` are *classes*.

Comment: Yups, the idea is store multiple points in tuple. As far as I know namedtuple is same with tuple but it is used names as index, and tuple use numerical index. (CMIIW) @falsetru

Comment: @Martijn Pieters But I didn't want make more classes. :'(

Answer (score 1):

You missed something here: `namedtuple()` *produces a new class*. From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple):

> Returns a **new tuple subclass** named *typename*. The new subclass is used to create tuple-like objects that have fields accessible by attribute lookup as well as being indexable and iterable.

(*Bold emphasis mine*).

Use those subclasses to create new *instances*:

```
Point = namedtuple("Point", "x y")
ROI = namedtuple("ROI", "point1 point2 point3 ... pointN")
roi = ROI(Point(10, 20), Point(11, 21), ...)
```

These instances then actually hold the values that the named attributes return:

```
roi.point1.x  # 10
roi.point2.y  # 21
```

Note that in keeping with the Python style guide I gave the attributes of the `ROI` type lowercase names.

I'd not use a named tuple just to produce numbered names. I'd just use a regular tuple and use indexing:

```
roi = (Point(10, 20), Point(11, 21), ...)
roi[0].x  # 10
roi[1].y  # 21
```

If you have a sequence of `(x, y)` tuples already, you can produce your `ROI` using a generator expression and the [`namedtuple._make()` class method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.somenamedtuple._make):

```
points = [(10, 20), (11, 21), ...]
roi = ROI._make(Point(*p) for p in points)
```

creates a new `Point()` instance for each tuple in `points`, and one new `ROI` instance holding all the `Point()` instances produced.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you should use a `NamedTuple` for `Point` but a regular `tuple` for `ROI`.

```
roi3 = (Point(x1, y1), Point(x2, y2), Point(x3, y3))
```

the only "tricky" part is that if you have only one point the syntax is

```
roi1 = (Point(x1, y1),) # comma is needed to make a 1-tuple
```

And of course you will access the points with

```
roi[0], roi[1], ... roi[n-1]
```

instead of by name

Comment: Why? You can use a named tuple for ROI just fine.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I'd say that a named tuple where the names are `point1`, `point2`, ... doesn't make much sense. Just my view of course.

Comment: Yes, sequential names where a normal tuple will do is indeed pointless. But the main confusion is from class vs. instance here.

Comment: used regular tuple will make me confuse because it is many point in one ROI. Actually in my code I didn't give name point1, point2, but the location that i hope. like at the cornerupperright, centerupper, and many else. @6502

Answer (score 0):

I thing it's better to use dictionary with points. Here is an idea:

```
from collections import namedtuple, defaultdict
Point = namedtuple('Point', ['x', 'y'])
ROI = defaultdict(Point)
ROI['Point1'] = Point(1, 1)
ROI['Point2'] = Point(5, 2)
print(ROI['Point1'].x, ROI['Point1'].y)
```

Comment: You don't get any benefit to using `defaultdict` here, as it will fail unless you make it e.g. `ROI = defaultdict(lambda: Point(0, 0))`

Comment: Hem.. if I see your idea, it is something like I do "ROI... = Point" for every points. if I didn't wrong. @Aris F.